# How can I add Javascript in the header of all post pages and only post pages

Tags: javascript, wp-head

I am using

```
add_action('wp_head', 'function_that_returns_js_string')
```

in `functions.php` but it is adding the string in the header across the site. How can this be narrowed down to be only included in post pages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the type of the queried object on the page and the post type:

```
function function_that_returns_js_string() {
  $obj = get_queried_object();
  $type = is_a($obj,'WP_Post');
  if (true === $type && 'post' == $obj->post_type) {
    echo 'your string';
  }
}
add_action('wp_head', 'function_that_returns_js_string');
```

However, I am concerned that you are inserting a script directly into the head of the page rather than enqueueing it, which is more standard practice. The same trick will work to conditionally enqueue:

```
function function_that_returns_js_string() {
  $obj = get_queried_object();
  $type = is_a($obj,'WP_Post');
  if (true === $type && 'post' == $obj->post_type) {
    wp_enqueue_script('jcrop');
  }
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'function_that_returns_js_string');
```